# Как на python сгруппировать данные таблицы, чтобы были учтены дубли?

Tags: python, pandas

Есть таблица с данными по рассылкам data:
title - тема письма
total - аудитория, количество людей, кому отправили это письмо
click_to_open - количество людей, которые открыли письмо

Некоторые темы писем дублируются, так как одно и то же письмо отправлялось на разные аудитории. То есть условно:

```
Письмо_1 - аудитория 100 человек - открыли 10  
Письмо_1 - аудитория 300 человек - открыли 50  
Письмо_2 - аудитория 100 человек - открыли 30
```

Я хочу объединить это в одну таблицу, где будет по каждому письму сумма:

```
Письмо_1 - аудитория 400 человек - открыли 60  
Письмо_2 - аудитория 100 человек - открыли 30
```

Но и при использовании `pivot_table`, и при `groupby` почему-то не учитываются те названия, которые задублированы. В исходном файле 600 строк, дублей - 200, уникальных - 400. В сводную таблицу попадают только 400 уникальных, а 200 дублей пропадают( Не понимаю, в чем проблема.

```
data.groupby('title').agg({'total' :'sum', 'click_to_open':'sum'})
```

Comment: А результат аггрегации какой? Покажите. Вы его куда-то присваиваете вообще? А данные числовые, не текстовые, которые вы суммируете? `sum` должны срабатывать.

Comment: Используя ваш код и данные из вопроса, получил требуемый результат. Думаю, что данные находятся не в том виде, который представлен в вопросе.

Comment: Результат у меня верный (все суммируется), но получается 400 строк всего (то есть только те, которые изначально не были задублированы), а должно быть 466 (проверила в Экселе в сводной). Ощущение, что дело не в цифрах, потому что если даже без них брать только title, то получается 400 строк всего(

Comment: Ну всё правильно, если уникальных `title` 400, то в результате группировки и получится 400 строк, что не так то? А числа просуммируются у совпадающих `title`.

Comment: А то, что в исходном файле их 600 всего. 400 неповторяющихся, и 200 - тех, у которых есть дубли. И дублирующиеся нужно тоже учесть.

Comment: Так они и учитываются - суммированием цифр по полям `total` и `click_to_open` для совпадающих `title`. Либо я чего-то не понял. Может у вас 400 уникальных это учитывая дубли и не дубли, просто уникальных? Тогда всё правильно работает.

Comment: В Экселе в сводной получается больше строк. Ощущение, что пропали некоторые.

Comment: Ну, попробуйте найти в чём разница с экселем, тогда можно будет дальше копать.